# The interval [a,a] has no length and has Lebesgue measure zero, but it is not the null set ....

Tags: measure-theory

I'm missing something fundamental, I think. Given a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ we define a measure $\mu: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as having two properties, the first of which, $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, is my problem.

The Lebesgue measure of intervals of the form $(a,b)$ is $\mathcal{l}((a,b)) = b-a.$ If b=a the value of the measure is $0$ but the set is not the null set. So, how do we know $\mathcal{l}$() satisfies the first condition and is therefore a measure? Do we just define it to be a property? If yes then all is good. If no, then I am missing something fundamental. I fear the answer is no.

Comment: When you say "null set," are you meaning the empty set or a [null set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set), which is a set of measure $0$? Regarding the question about Lebesgue measure, $l$ isn't the Lebesgue measure itself, it's used to define the Lebesgue outer measure first.

Comment: A measure must be defined on a sigma algebra, and your $l$ function is not.  We extend $l$ to have domain equal to the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.  The simplest part of extending it is to **define** $l(\phi)=0$. The extensions to other Borel sets is the hard part.

Comment: @KyleMiller: It's good to learn something every day. I always thought (from early college days) that the empty set was another name for the null set. Now I know! I meant the empty set. The second part of your comment is unclear to me. If my partial definition of the Lebesgue measure is not correct, could you give me the correct definition please? Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @David. Thank you, I see why you think that is the problem. I'm not saying that only the empty set has measure $0$. I guess I had just assumed that the definition of `length' would lead to an empty set with measure zero. But as I said, the zero length interval is not empty - though it has measure zero. So, that begs the question, do we just define the measure of the empty set for the Lebesgue measure to be zero? It seems so, if I read the comment after yours correctly. And that's fine - I've no problem with that, I've just not seen it stated explicitly.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for weighing in. Why do you say that the measure is not on a sigma field. I specified a measurable space. I your objection that I did not say  $\mathcal{F}}$ is the Borel sigma field? Orr is it the way I specified the intervals?  Your third statement gives me hope that all I need to do is as that condition. That would make me happy. I confess your last statement I don't understand.

Comment: @TonyK: *It's good to learn something every day.* --- I don't know when I first realized that "null set" is used in ways besides the empty set, but I do know that as you get further in math and have seen enough books (especially random browsing in a good university library) and papers, it becomes like the phrase "natural number" (which has two widely used meanings). FYI, each of [these papers that actually have "null set" in their title](https://zbmath.org/?au=&ti=%22null+set%22). In fact, [even more papers have "null sets" in their title](https://zbmath.org/?q=ti%3A%22null+sets%22).

Comment: You defined your $L$ function as $L((a,b))=b-a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$. So you only defined it on intervals of the form $(a,b)$, which does not include sets such as $\phi$ or $\{3.5\}$ or $(0,1] \cup [3.5,5]$ or $\{x \in [0,1]: x \notin \mathbb{Q}\}$. A deep theorem of measure theory says that it can be uniquely extended to be a measure on all Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. We can infer that this measure must satisfy $L(\phi)=0$ and $L(\{3.5\})=0$ and $L((0,1] \cup [3.5, 5]) = 2.5$ and $L(\{x \in [0,1]: x \notin \mathbb{Q}\})=1$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Interesting, I don't feel so bad now.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the clarification, it helps. I'm guessing the deep theorem is the caratheodory extension theorem (given your use of *extension*). I've heard of it but that's about it.

Comment: Yes, it is the Caratheodory extension theorem. I summarize my comments in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes my comments above.

It was assumed that $L$ is a function that maps intervals of the type $(a,b)$ to the length of the interval:
$$L((a,b)) = b-a \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b$$

This function $L$ is currently only defined on subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are intervals of the form $(a,b)$ where $a, b$ are real numbers and $a<b$.  This collection of intervals does not form a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. Also, this collection of intervals does not include important subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such as
\begin{align}
&\phi\\
&\{3.5\}\\
&[3.5, 5)\\
&[0,1] \cup [3.5, 5)\\
&\{x \in [0,1] : x \notin \mathbb{Q} \}
\end{align}
However, it can be shown that the sigma algebra generated by the intervals of the type $(a,b)$ is equal to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (the standard Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$). The collection of sets $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ includes all intervals of the type $(a,b)$, but also includes many more subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (including the ones listed above). An important question is whether or not we can **define** $L(A)$ on all of the additional sets $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ that are **not** of the form $(a,b)$ in such a way that the **extended function** $L:\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a valid measure, and in a way that preserves the value $L((a,b))=b-a$ for all of the sets $(a,b)$ on which $L$ was originally defined.

A deep theorem of measure theory called the **Caratheodory extension theorem** proves that such an extension of $L$ exists and is unique. So we must define $L(A)$ for the additional sets $A$, but there is one and only one way to define these values while being consistent with the requirements of a measure. This is like a Sudoku puzzle where some values of $L(A)$ are already given to us, we must find the missing values $L(A)$ for the remaining sets $A$, and there is only one way to correctly do it.

We know that such an extension requires us to **define** $L(\phi)=0$ simply because all measures must satisfy that. Also, assuming $L$ is the extended measure, we see that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $\epsilon>0$
$$ \phi \subseteq \{x\} \subseteq (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$$
and so we must have
$$ 0 \leq L(\{x\})\leq L((x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)) = 2\epsilon$$
This holds for all $\epsilon>0$, and so we must have $L(\{x\})=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. From this, together with basic properties of a measure, we can also infer
\begin{align}
&L([3.5, 5)) = L(\{3.5\}\cup (3.5,5)) = L(\{3.5\})+L((3.5, 5)) = 0 + 1.5 = 1.5\\
&L([0,1])=1\\
&L([0,1]\cup [3.5,5)) = 2.5\\
&L([0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}) = L\left(\cup_{x \in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}}\{x\} \right) = \sum_{x \in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}} L(\{x\})=0\\
&L(\{x \in [0,1]: x \notin \mathbb{Q}\}) = 1
\end{align}

Comment: Very clear, and with some reading on the extension theorem in the meantime it begins to make sense. I really appreciate you taking the time to pull it together.